# Does a geotagged image contain information about its accuracy?

Tags: accuracy, geotag

When I view my current location on Google Maps on my Android it shows me a circle of uncertainty. If I take a geotagged picture it will off course contain information about its Lat or Lon. Does it also contain information concerning accuracy of this geotagging?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [Exif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) standards, yes there are attributes relating to GPS accuracy such as `GPSDOP` ([Dilution of precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilution_of_precision_%28GPS%29)). See [this table](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/GPS.html) for a list of these tags.

You could also use a tool like [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/) to extract and view the Exif data yourself.

However, not all devices actually use GPS but use [other forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_phone_tracking) of [geolocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geolocation) such as cellular [multilateration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilateration), and others record only the bare minimum (coordinate tags), so these tags are likely to be empty more often than not.